# Load a font from JAR for FOP

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop

I have a TTF font in `fonts` directory in the JAR with my application.

```
 myapp.jar /
     fop /
        config.xml
        font.ttf
```

I create my FOP this way:

```
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    fopFactory.setStrictValidation(false);
    fopFactory.setUserConfig(getClasspathFile("/fop/config.xml"));
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
   ...
```

How do I configure `config.xml` to embeddd `font.ttf` in the PDF file I am rendering?

Answer (score 8):

it seems that my post is too late, but may be it'll be useful for the others.
[java 8, fop 2.1]

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
...
        @SneakyThrows
            private FopFactory getFopFactory(){
                InputStream fopConfigStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/fop/config.xml");
                FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI(), new CustomPathResolver());
                FopFactory factory = builder.setConfiguration(new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build(fopConfigStream)).build();
                fopConfigStream.close();
                return factory;
            }
    ...
        private static final class CustomPathResolver implements ResourceResolver {
            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
                return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(uri.toString()).openConnection()
                        .getOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
                InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("fop/" + FilenameUtils.getName(uri));
                return new Resource(inputStream);
            }
        }
```

config.xml:

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
              <font kerning="yes" embed-url="font.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
                <font-triplet name="Font name" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
              </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```