# How to Configure FOP for Fonts included within a Spring-Boot/Camel Microservice

Tags: apache-camel, apache-fop

I'm using the Camel FOP Component version 2.19.1 which brings in the FOP 2.1 dependency.  The application must be self-contained - deployable as a fat WAR. or JAR and Dockerized, or run within a Tomcat container.  I have the fonts in the "resources" project folder which means Maven will place the font files at the root of my classpath - directly under the /classes folder within the WAR.

My FOP configuration file is loading correctly, and the fonts are found fine if I just place my fonts in a local directory and hardcode the absolute path to them like `embed-url="file:///C:/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.ttf"`.  However when I try a relative URL as in `embed-url="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.ttf"` an exception is thrown saying "URI is not absolute".  This makes little sense, since the FOP documentation states that a relative URI can be used and that's what the `<font-base>` is for!  Very confusing...

I've tried a lot of things without success over the past few days, such as even replacing `file:` in the URI with `classpath:`, however unlike the other Apache projects it seems to only support `file:`.  I've even tried removing my font registration from the config file completely, and just using `<auto-detect />`.  While it finds all the fonts on my system (in about 5 minutes!) it does not find the font at the root of my classpath.  Additionally even if it did work, I'd prefer FOP not to scan every installed system font and attempt to create TEMP cache files because this must be deployable in Docker containers within a cloud environment.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with the current FOP implementation?

Here is an example of a FOP config file I tried:

```
<fop version="1.0">
<renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
        <font-base>./</font-base>
        <fonts>
        <!-- This of course works -->
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="file:///C:/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.ttf">
                <font-triplet name="Helvetica Neue LT Std" style="normal"
                    weight="normal" />
            </font>

            <!-- This results in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute -->
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.ttf">
                <font-triplet name="Helvetica Neue LT Std" style="normal"
                    weight="bold" />
            </font>
            <auto-detect />
        </fonts>
    </renderer>
</renderers>
```

Comment: I suggest to look into Apache FOP and how it can load resources and what it support, and if loading from classpath is even possible. If you use Docker you can embed the fonts in a folder in the docker image, which can then be loaded from FOP from the file system

Comment: According to [FOP's documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#autodetect), fonts inside a JAR file in the classpath can be configured using `<auto-detect/>` provided they have an  _appropriate description in the manifest file_. Haven't tried this myself, though.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the first thing I tried was including the fonts in their own JAR included in a WAR with the suggested manifest entries (inserted via a Maven plugin).  Always the exception is thrown. Oddly enough, the same JAR works fine when using FOP in standalone mode with the Jar in the fop/lib folder with the other dependencies.  What I'm attempting should be easier since I can see this as being a more and more common use case as the popularity of microservices continues to grow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745133/load-a-font-from-jar-for-fop